# how do I select this in JSOUP?

Tags: java, jsoup

I am trying to select this:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RgQIb.png)

this seems to work:

```
final String title = doc.select(".size-dropdown-block").text();
```

but it gives me all of them, i only want the last 4 "li"

Comment: don't take screenshots, type everything in

Answer (score 1):

```
Elements liElems = doc.select(".size-dropdown-block");

int lastX = 4;
List<Element> liList = liElems.subList(liElems.size() - lastX, liElems.size());
```

Your `List` would now have the last four `li` elements you need.